# NHibernate InMemory tests

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate, in-memory-database

I'm trying to use in memory test with NHibernate, and i succeeded to do that in this little project :
https://github.com/demojag/NHibernateInMemoryTest

As you can see from the map of the object i had to comment this line :
 *//SchemaAction.None();  Test will fail. this option hide the schema exportation.*

this comment is just i guess I've made because so far i haven't found serious documentation about Schema Actions.

I'm doing those tests because i have an existing situation i would like to test in memory but all the entity maps have the option SchemaActions.None(), and when i try to execute the in memory test i get a lot of "no such tables".

I would like to know if exist a way to keep the Schema action option set to none and export the schema anyway ? (i know that can be an encapsulation violation so it would not really have a lot of sense).

I would like to leave this option set to none because is a "DatabaseFirst" application , and i can't take the risk to drop the database and re create it every time the configuration is build, but i guess, if in the configuration i don't specify the instruction "exposeConfiguration" and SchemaExport, i can be pretty safe.

Thank you in advice

Giuseppe.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override any and all settings in the HBM or Fluent NHibernate mappings via the `NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BeforeBindMapping` event which gives you programmatic runtime access to NHibernate's internal model for a mapping. See the example below which sets up BeforeBindMapping event handler which overrides the SchemaAction specified in the mapping to whatever you want.

```
public NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration BuildConfiguration()
{
    var configuration = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();

    configuration.BeforeBindMapping += OnBeforeBindMapping;

    // A bunch of other stuff...

    return configuration;
}

private void OnBeforeBindMapping( object sender, NHibernate.Cfg.BindMappingEventArgs bindMappingEventArgs )
{
    // Set all mappings to use the fully qualified namespace to avoid class name collision
    bindMappingEventArgs.Mapping.autoimport = false;

    // Override the schema action to all
    foreach ( var item in bindMappingEventArgs.Mapping.Items )
    {
        var hbmClass = item as NHibernate.Cfg.MappingSchema.HbmClass;

        if ( hbmClass != null )
        {
            hbmClass.schemaaction = "all";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting any result with that :(..
But my question is, is that necessary? I mean, if in my prod configuration i don't expose the schema generation, i should be safe...right?